# Android Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, splash-screen

This following code results in this output, I cant see my text view.
[image]
What should I do to see my text view?
It would leave this splash screen...
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hello.agam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="@string/hello"/>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have also tried this:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         tv.setText("Hello, Android");
         setContentView(tv);
```

Comment: what...? i'm confused, what are you asking.

Comment: Is this your first time running an Android app on the emulator?  Can you successfully run one of the Android sample apps on the emulator, like notepad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wait for the emulator to boot up before your app will load. Depends how fast your computer is could be 2-5 minutes. Do not shut it down between deployments for faster testing.

That is the Android bootup splash screen you are seeing while it loads. You will see a what looks like a normal android phone when complete.

Comment: You can also greatly speed up emulator start-ups (after the first) by enabling snapshots for the AVD in the AVD manager and then enable "Launch from snapshot" and "Save to snapshot" in the launch dialog (when you click on the "Start" button in the AVD manager).